# $(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}:f)\stackrel{?}{=}(\mathfrak{a}:f)+(\mathfrak{b}:f)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with unit and $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ are ideals of $R$.  We can define $(\mathfrak{a}:f)=\{g\in R\mid gf\in \mathfrak{a}\}$ for $f\in R$. I can see that $(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}:f)\supseteq (\mathfrak{a}:f)+(\mathfrak{b}:f)$. Does the reverse inclusion hold?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking if, for all $f$, there exists $n$ such that the equality is true?

Comment: no, i'm asking if it's true for all $n$. i changed the question a bit so that this is clear.

Comment: I think the power $n$ is confusing. $f$ is just some element of $R$, right?

Comment: that's a good point. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $R = k[x,y]$, $\mathfrak{a} = (x^2)$, $\mathfrak{b} = (y^2)$, $f = x + y$. Then $(x^2 : x+y) = (x^2) \qquad (**)$, $(y^2 : x+y) = (y^2)$, but $((x^2,y^2) : x+y) \ni x-y$.

(**): if $(x + y)r \in (x^2)$, then $(x+y)r = x^2s$ for some $s$. Now $x^2 \mid (x+y)r \implies x \mid r$ since $x$ is prime, so $r = xt$ for some $t$. Then $(x+y)r = (x+y)xt = x^2s$, so $(x+y)t = xs$ (as $R$ is a domain), hence $x \mid (x+y)t \implies x \mid t \implies r \in (x^2)$.

Comment: @adrido A simple remark: this example is in some sense minimal, since the equality $(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{b}:f)=(\mathfrak{a}:f)+(\mathfrak{b}:f)$ holds for $R$ a principal ideal domain. (Proving this could be a useful exercise for you.)

Comment: @user121097: it was indeed a good exercise. thank you!